# Whats happening to my off shore money?

Tags: tropico-4

I know some edicts cost you money from your Swiss Bank Account, but no matter what I do when I start a new level in a campaign (if I save and exit the game before hand) I end up with less money in my Swiss Account.   I know I'm loosing money as I've done plenty of the campaign and sandbox missions, and at various times peaked over half a mission, but I seem to keep dropping to around ~100K.

I am more than half way through the campaign so:

> I have completed the mission where you are forced out and have to get a new identity, so I guess you do drop money there (as it says you lose your fortune) but I wouldn't expect this to carry on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No answer, it seems offshore fluctuates depending on the mission.